# Duplicating Object

Tags: java, object, duplication

I am trying to duplicate an object with no success.  I tried

1. Serialization
2. Cloning

both methods don't work for me.

When I used serialization (I am using the technique specified here [Faster Deep Copies of Java Objects](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)) I got `NullPointerException`. With cloning I got original object reference.

Scenario is:

I have one abstract class A with data `char[][] board` and an extended class `B`. I want to duplicate the data `board` for this I implemented two methods in `B` - `getboard()` and `setboard()` and implemented a clone method such that

```
B b1 = new B;
B.initialize();
B b2 new B;
B2 = B1.clone(B2)
```

But this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :-)

```
       public B clone()  {

            B N = new B();
            try {
                    N = (B)super.clone();
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            N.setBoard(this.getBoard());
            return N;
    }
```

Regarding the serialization, after deserializing when i try to draw the board it is giving me `NullPointerException`. I conclude that, deserialization didn't work properly.

Comment: Show the code inside of your clone method.

Comment: Do you know why you got a null pointer? The Serialization technique is pretty commonly used.

Comment: You should add that code to the post itself as an update.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `clone` method in `B`:

```
public class B {
    private int f1;
    private String f2;

    @Override
    public B clone() {
        B clone = new B();
        clone.f1 = this.f1;
        clone.f2 = this.f2;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

And use it to create duplicate:

```
B b1 = new B();
//...
B b2 = b1.clone();
```

**Update:**

```
public B clone()  {
        B N = new B();
        try {
                N = (B)super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        N.setBoard(this.getBoard());
        return N;
}
```

Try the following (assuming that `B` implements `Cloneable`):

```
@Override
public B clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (B) super.clone();
}
```

**Update:**

Custom implementation for `board`:

```
class B implements Cloneable {
    private char[][] board;   

    @Override
    public B clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B clone = (B) super.clone();
        clone.board = new char[this.board.length][];
        for(int i=0; i<this.board.length; i++) {
            clone.board[i] = new char[this.board[i].length];
            System.arraycopy(this.board[i], 0, clone.board[i], 0, this.board[i].length);
        }
        return clone;        
    }

    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(char[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(this.board);
    }
}
```

Comment: clone() should never use new B(). this will break if B is subclassed, use B clone = (B) super.clone();

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: I am confused here. We are creating a duplicate of `B`. Now if we do `B clone = (B) super.clone();`, how do `super.clone()` return an instance of `B`. The super class (`Object` in this case) don't even know about `B`. Can you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

Over the time I have found out that using a third party library to do object cloning can be a life saver. One of the projects I'd recommend is "Cloning", available at http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Here's an example:

```
Cloner cloner=new Cloner();

MyClass clone=cloner.deepClone(o);
// clone is a deep-clone of o
```

Comment: I can't use third party libraries :-(